# Unable to set a map on eclipse - android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I followed this guide:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

And did these steps:

- Got a key from google (after finding my sha-1 fingerprint from:
  eclipse->preferences->android->build).
- Imported the google_play_services_lib and added it as a library of
  the project.
- Added those to my **Manifest file**:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.xxxxx.yyyyy.premission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true" />
  ```

  ...
   
  ...

**My xml layout file**: (activity_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/header"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and my main java file:**

```
package com.xxxxx.yyyyy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I would very appreciate any help because I can't seem to find why it isn't working.
Thanks

Comment: `I can't seem to find why it isn't working` it will be difficult for us too, since you have not described what the problem is.

Comment: sorry simon, this is the error from the console:
"Error in an XML file: aborting build."

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this guide I wrote that will give you a map in your applcation in 10 simple steps:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

If after you completed this and still don't have a map try to recreate the key and to re-install the application completely (remove the previous version)

Comment: Hi Emil, there is one thing that comes to mind: 
when i searched for my SHA-1 fingerprint, I didn't manage to get it from the cmd (I have Windows 7) because the keytool command was unrecognized.
however, i'v found a SHA-1 fingerprint in: 
eclipse->preferences->android->build
do you think this might not be the right SHA-1 fingerprint?

Comment: It's might be... try to reach the location of the keytool in the java directory when you are cmd before using it. or just follow this guide to get the key and see if they match:  http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403

Comment: Okay Emil: 1. I followed your guide and i must say i think its excellent: it overlaps all the imformation i gatthered from 3 other tutorials, + it was shorter and more user friendly

2. its the same SHA-1 so there is not problem here

3. although i followed your guide- it still doesn't work and there are two strange things:
1. this line returns an error:
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
(xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto")

Comment: 2. when i clean the project i get the following error:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'google-play-services_lib'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'.